# Problem with window.top.close() in Unified Interface by Solution Checker

Tags: interface, dynamics-crm

While moving to Unified Interface from Classic Interface in Dynamics 365 CE, we found that window.close() does not work. So, we used window.top.close() which works. But, when we checked the solution in Solution Checker, we got the following message.

"Usage of 'window.top' or 'window.parent.parent' was detected. This will likely result in cross-origin security errors when hosted outside of the primary web client. Develop an alternate approach."

Has anyone else encountered this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Yes we did encountered the same. Reason been Microsoft is requesting us not to use unsupported code and as far as I know `window.close´ it unsupported

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: did you managed to solve it?

Comment: No, not yet. We have decided to keep it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have moved from `window.close` to `formContext.ui.close()`

But this was when we wanted to close Record window.

official link for Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-ui/close